# add custom order attribute to the order from in magento admin

Tags: attributes, magento

I've added a custom order attribute and updated the onepage checkout page.
Now I'm trying to add this attribute to the new order form in the admin.
I'm trying to extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account and add a new field in the _prepareForm() method similar to the way the Group and Email fields are added.

How do I get the order attribute?
I've tried several ways but nothing works.
This is how I'm creating the custom order attribute in the mysql-install file:

```
$attribute  = array(
        'type'          => 'int',
        'label'         => 'myattr',
        'visible'       => false,
        'required'      => false,
        'user_defined'  => false,
        'searchable'    => false,
        'filterable'    => false,
        'comparable'    => false,
);
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'myattr', $attribute);
```

and this is how I'm trying to get the attribute:

```
$res = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$eav = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$attr = $eav->getAttribute('sales/order', 'myattr');
```

or with this:

```
$entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('order');
$entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();

$attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                ->setCodeFilter('myattr')
                ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                ->getFirstItem();
```

or this:

```
$order = Mage::getResourceSingleton('sales/order');
$myAttr = $order->getAttribute('myattr');
```

None of them work.

Comment: Abandoned questions are a pain. Has your issue resolved (with or without help from answers)? If so, please consider answering the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified that the attribute is being added to `eav_attribute` table in the database with the correct `entity_type_id`? (I think sales_order is 11 by default, but don't assume that)

At first glance, it looks like you should be using

```
$installer->addAttribute('sales/order', 'myattr', $attribute);
```

HTH,
JD

Comment: I'm using $installer->addAttribute('order', 'myattr', $attribute); but I think it's ok because I'm using the Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup class in my sql installer. Order uses a flat table, sales_flat_order, so I probably need to add field to the form in a different way than customer or address attributes. Is there a way to add it to the _prepreForm of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form_Account? Maybe a similar file to see how it should be done?

Comment: You didn't answer my first question.  Is the attribute in the `eav_attribute` table.  If it's not there, then you need to change the way that you are calling `$installer->adAttribute(...)`

Comment: The attribute is not in the eav_attribute but non of the sales_order fields are in the eav_attribute table.

Comment: I see 123 attributes in `eav_attribute` with `entity_type_id` = 11.... attribute_id entity_type_id  attribute_code
         153             11        adjustment_ne
         152             11        adjustment_po
         125             11        applied_rule_
         169             11        base_adjustme
         168             11        base_adjustme
         127             11        base_currency
         157             11        base_discount
         159             11        base_grand_to

Answer (score 0):

Sales/Order used to use the EAV Model which supports attributes, that was before 1.4.0 or so not sure.
I think now you should do:

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'my_column', 'decimal(12,4)');
```

you can still add the attribute as static field

```
$installer->addAttribute('order', 'my_column', array('type'=>'static'));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I noticed after much trial-and-error was that the new attribute must have a default (non-null) value in order to work. Somehow the attribute is not writable if it has a 'NULL' value in the database. So using this attribute options array worked for me:

```
$attribute  = array(
'type'          => 'int',
'label'         => 'myattr',
'default'       => 0,
'visible'       => false,
'required'      => false,
'user_defined'  => true,
'searchable'    => false,
'filterable'    => false,
'comparable'    => false );
```